# Javascript : do a second treatment when array filtering is complete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I have to manipulate an array  by using two methods , one after the other :

1. filter array
2. then , sort it

**my filter method is the following**

```
  filterArray(list){
    return list.filter(item=> !this.myCondition(item));
  }
```

**my sort method is the following :**

```
sortArray(list) {
    return list.sort((a, b) =>
      new Date(b.beginDate).getTime() - new Date(a.beginDate).getTime()
    );
}
```

I want to control it, by the way, ***that its complete filtering and then do the sorting***

I've tried this :

```
myData = myData.filterArray(myData).sortArray(myData);
```

But i'm not sure that it's the cleanest way 
*(Note : i want to keep sorting and filtering methods separated)*

**best ways to do it ?**

Comment: that is fine. btw, what format does your date have?

Comment: Can't you use `this` inside `sortArray` instead of passing `myData` as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

[Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) **won't** **return** a **new** sorted **array**. it will sort **in-place** which means that it will **mutate** the **array**. thus returning something from your sort function and storing it makes no sense. if you you want to prevent mutation of original array you should clone it on your sort function manually, then sorting it, then returning. to keep pure functions without side effects;

```
sortArray(list) {
    let listClone = list.slice(0); // some fast cloning method
    listClone.sort((a, b) =>
      new Date(b.beginDate).getTime() - new Date(a.beginDate).getTime()
    );
    return listClone 
}
```

Since filter returns new array every time, your code works just fine; but if you use your sort function separately it will have side effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
  myData = myData
  .filter(item => !this.myCondition(item))
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.beginDate).getTime() - new Date(a.beginDate).getTime());
```

Each line was assigned with different job.